# Can I set add something to PATH, system-wide for all users, which has LOWEST precedence?

Tags: bash, shell, security, environment-variables, path

I can put this in `/etc/environment` and all users will have it:

```
PATH=/opt/my/bin
```

As I understand it, `/etc/environment` sets initial environment variables, then `.profile`, `.bashrc` and similar happen later.

This results in something like

```
#> echo $PATH
/opt/my/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
```

As it happens, `/opt/my/bin` and the files within it are not owned by root but by other intermediate-level administrators. On a shared system this opens the door to exploits if a sub-root administrator goes rogue, or is somehow tricked into pushing out a malicious (or vulnerable) file whose name clashes with a system tool.

As part of a defence-in-depth strategy it would seem a sensible precaution to have `/opt/my/bin` come to the right of everything else. (Paranoid users and script authors will type `/sbin/foo <args>` but let's not rely on that.)

Can I include a directory in `PATH` in such a way that

a) all users have it, including newly-created users, without pushing out individual `.bashrc` (or similar) files to them, and

b) takes effect *after* `PATH` has been set to include `/sbin`, `/bin`, and friends?

Comment: use `/etc/profile`

Comment: Ah right. Want to make that an actual answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `/etc/profile` or `/etc/profile.d/` folder